# C# ValidationAttribute for enums

Tags: c#, enums

I have the following enums:

```
public enum FirstEnum : short
{
    Unknown = -1,
    Red = 2,
    Green = 3
}

public enum SecondEnum 
{
    Unknown = -1,
    Orange = 2,
    Apple = 3
}
```

I now want to write a data annotation attribute so I can validate properties. So say I have a class:

```
public class MyClass
{
    [EnumValidation(AllowUnKnown = true)]
    public FirstEnum  First { get; set; }

    [EnumValidation(AllowUnKnown = false)]
    public SecondEnum  Second { get; set; }
}
```

and my validation attribute is as follows:

```
public class EnumValidationAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public bool AllowUnKnown { get; set; }

    public override bool IsValid(object aValue)
    {
        bool valid = true;
        int enumValue = (int) aValue;  //** Cannot do hard cast
        if (enumValue == -1 && !AllowUnKnown)
                valid = false;

        return valid;
    }
}
```

so now he issue comes in that I can no longer do a hard cast of the enum member to an int as FirstEnum is a short.

So how do I safely determine the value for the enum member? (I cannot change the declaration of FirstEnum)

Comment: Does this work: `int enumValue = Convert.ToInt32(b);`

Comment: **byte** and -1? byte.MinValue is 0. Even compiler throw error. Why do you need byte as enum?

Comment: @Klaudiuszbryjamus My bad... I meant a short.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens works perfectly. Don't know how I missed that. Love it when its so simple. Tested with long, short, byte (yes I realise -1 issue), int and all is well. Happy to mark this as the selected answer if you want to add it as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work:

```
int enumValue = Convert.ToInt32(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can't use `-1` value for `byte` variable then you should change `Unknown` value to any other valid `byte`. `FirstEnum`is not compilable.

Also, you can use `Convert.ToInt32` method to cast byte value to integer. Actually, next code write `true` to the console:

```
byte x1 = 1;
object o1 = x1;
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToInt32(o1) == 1);
```

So you can implement your method with convertation:

```
public override bool IsValid(object aValue)
{
    int enumValue = Convert.ToInt32(aValue);
    return !(enumValue == -1 && !AllowUnKnown);
}
```

Comment: Also, having `Unknown` be `0` is good enum practice -- that's the default initialization value.

Comment: @Peter Unfortunately the system was already using 0 for the "All" condition so this cannot be changed at this point.